# Auto Post on Twitter after authentication : getting Invalid access token error

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Here I need to automatically post on Twitter after authentication.

My code

```
<?php
session_start();
include("twitteroauth.php");


define('CONSUMER_KEY','zubLdCze6Erz9SVNIgG3w');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET','ZnZQ77bNnpBER2aSxTQGEXToAQODz9qEBSAXIdeYw');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK','http://dev.pubs.positive-dedicated.net/Licensee/addPubEventWeekly.php');


/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

/* Get temporary credentials. */
 $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
 $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
 $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];


switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);    
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
?>
```

and

```
ksort($_SESSION);
                                    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth('zubLdCze6Erz9SVNIgG3w','ZnZQ77bNnpBER2aSxTQGEXToAQODz9qEBSAXIdeYw',$_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
                                    print_r($tweet);
                                    $account = $tweet->get('account/verify_credentials');

                                    $message = "This is an example twitter post using PHP";
                                    $postVal = $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
```

But here I am getting "Invalid/Expired access token" Error.

I have changed twittreauth.php library file also from 1.0 to 1.1 from here

```
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
```

Please suggest how to fix this